# Postgres split word with number and letters and amel case into two columns

Tags: regex, postgresql, camelcasing

I have a bunch of addresses that I need to split where the street number meets the city, and where its camelcase , ie:

255 S Broad St Ste 1600Goldberg Miller & Rubin PcPhiladelphia, PA, 19107-4534

You can see the number/string word is "1600Goldberg". And the CamelCase word is "PcPhiladelphia". Is there any expression to add a space?

The new cell should read:

121 S Broad St Ste 1600 Goldberg Miller & Rubin Pc Philadelphia, PA, 19107-4534

It should split all CamelCase and alphanumeric words with a space.

Comment: I figured out the camel case part:

update table set address =  regexp_replace(address, '([a-z])([A-Z])', '\1 \2','g')

Comment: I think the second part is something like this, but I need a space, instead of replacing it:

select address, regexp_replace(address, '(?=\w*[0-9])(?=\w*[a-z])\w+', '\1 \2', 'g') from table;

Answer (score 0):

Search for a digit or a lower case letter followed by an upper case letter.

```
SELECT regexp_replace('255 S Broad St Ste 1600Goldberg Miller & Rubin PcPhiladelphia, PA, 19107-4534', '([\da-z])([A-Z])', '\1 \2', 'g');
```

That gets you:

```
| regexp_replace                                                                  |
| :------------------------------------------------------------------------------ |
| 255 S Broad St Ste 1600 Goldberg Miller & Rubin Pc Philadelphia, PA, 19107-4534 |
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=93f19a4339354c900a7bff25964502f4)